# Custom session Handler essential issue

Tags: php, session, handler

currently I am writing an PHP Custom Session handler and I stuck at an essential problem

1. Do I need to start the session before initializing the session handler, after that or in the session handler class itself?
2. Where do I habe to call the session_set_save_handler() (at the moment I call it in the Session handler constructor)?

If I start the session before initializing the handler, the database will not be filled and I cant see any errors in the apache error log / webpage. In addidtion I will be redirected to the start page as in the normal case.

Then I tried to start the session after initializing and I can see some errors and I wont be redirected to the start page.

In the last case I tried to start it in the constructor before and after the session_set_save_handler() and its the same behaviour as described before.

can anyone show me the right way to that problem ?

Comment: Define "some errors"....

Comment: well I mean an error that something is not defined - and also my "die()"s will not be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to start the session before initializing the session
>   handler, after that or in the session handler class itself?

After you create the instance of your class, call the `session_start()`

```
<?php
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    // implement interfaces here
}

$handler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();

// proceed to set and retrieve values by key from $_SESSION
```

> Where do I have to call the session_set_save_handler() (at the moment
>   I call it in the Session handler constructor)?

Please refer above example.

More detailed info on PHP Manual **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php)**